# Drawing a Polygon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, graphics, polygon

I am using Google Maps API V3 to draw a polygon based on a path, which is an array of random unsorted coordinate points (LatLng). This produces the shape below:

**Polylines intersect!!**
[image: Polylines interesct!]

**Problem:** Since the shape of the Polygon depends on the order of the points in the path, how can I sort the path to create a polygon where no line intersects and no holes are formed? There is also a reference point (not shown in images) that the polygon must enclose. I believe this require a sorting algorithm, which I cannot find!

**No intersection :)**
[image]

**Although Javascript is used to produce this polygon, please feel free to use any language to solve this problem**

**EDIT:  There is a *reference point* that the polygon must enclose, but this point will not be any vertex of the polygon**

Comment: There are multiple polygons that could be created from those points.  Is the one in the picture the exact one you are looking for?  And if so, what defines that one to be the right one?

Comment: The right polygon that I am looking for is one where all the points map out one continuous area with no holes or intersecting of lines. If there are different solutions to this, all should work.

Comment: @Nyxynyx - What do you mean by "all should work"?  Do you mean the algorithm should identify all valid solutions for the set of points, or any 1 valid solution?

Comment: I see what a few of you meant. There is a reference point that the polygon must enclose, but this point will not be any vertex of the polygon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fun question.  I believe this works, but please test it out.  It's been a long long time since trig.

http://jsfiddle.net/9DHSf/3/

The comments basically explain it.  I find a "central" point (not sure if this is bulletproof, there may be a better way of calculating this or it may not matter that much), figure out how many degrees around that point each point is and then order them by that.  Tested it with various points and it seems to work.

```
var points = [
                {x: 40, y: 40},
                {x: 60, y: 40},
                {x: 60, y: 60},
                {x: 40, y: 60},                
                {x: 0, y: 50},
                {x: 50, y: 0},
                {x: 50, y: 100},
                {x: 100, y: 50}
            ];



// get the canvas element using the DOM
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
if (canvas.getContext) {

    // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";


    // calculate max and min x and y
    var minX = points[0].x;
    var maxX = points[0].x;
    var minY = points[0].y;
    var maxY = points[0].y;

    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i].x < minX) minX = points[i].x;
        if (points[i].x > maxX) maxX = points[i].x;
        if (points[i].y < minY) minY = points[i].y;
        if (points[i].y > maxY) maxY = points[i].y;
    }


    // choose a "central" point
    var center = {
        x: minX + (maxX - minX) / 2,
        y: minY + (maxY - minY) / 2
    };

    // precalculate the angles of each point to avoid multiple calculations on sort
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i].angle = Math.acos((points[i].x - center.x) / lineDistance(center, points[i]));

        if (points[i].y > center.y) {
            points[i].angle = Math.PI + Math.PI - points[i].angle;
        }
    }

    // sort by angle
    points = points.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.angle - b.angle;
    });

    // Draw shape
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }

    ctx.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}


function lineDistance(point1, point2) {
    var xs = 0;
    var ys = 0;

    xs = point2.x - point1.x;
    xs = xs * xs;

    ys = point2.y - point1.y;
    ys = ys * ys;

    return Math.sqrt(xs + ys);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**  After reading your edit, if this "reference point" is known and within the polygon, you should replace "center" with this point.

Comment: It occurs to me that if more than two points are at exactly the same angle, funny things could happen, so you may want to add a secondary sort of distance from the "center".  There are probably other special cases that may cause an issue, like a point being at EXACTLY the "center".

Comment: Will try this out! For my case, none of the point will be at the same exact location as the reference point, thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have at most a few dozen points to consider, use a TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem) algorithm to order the points.  For Euclidean-distance TSP paths, the path does not cross itself.  A lot of TSP code is available [online](http://www.aridolan.com/ga/gaa/gaa.html#DemoTsp) including applets.

A TSP path goes through all presented points.  If you want to go through only "outer" points, use a Convex Hull algorithm.  It will give points in order on the smallest convex polygon enclosing all points.

Comment: Are there TSP algorithms that have solutions that include enclosing a point within the polygon? I left this part out of the original question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "alpha shape" and "concave hull" are noteworthy