# PHP / Mongo geoJSON Loop is not valid

Tags: php, mongodb, geojson

I'm passing in some coordinates to mongo to do a geo search. It works fine if the coordinates don't intersect (for instance a figure eight). But when two lines intersect it gives the `loop is not valid`. Is there any way to find the intersection and split all these loops up?

Note there could be many.

**EDIT:** I added the sample query and error. Note that I understand why it's happening, I'm just wondering if there is some known way to split those loops up into separate polygon's (some algorithm or within Mongo).

**Query:**

```
db.items.find({
    "address.location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [-97.209091, 49.905691],
                    [-97.206345, 49.918072],
                    [-97.178879, 49.919399],
                    [-97.165146, 49.907903],
                    [-97.164459, 49.892865],
                    [-97.180939, 49.889326],
                    [-97.197418, 49.895077],
                    [-97.200165, 49.902596],
                    [-97.203598, 49.919399],
                    [-97.216644, 49.928682],
                    [-97.244797, 49.927356],
                    [-97.255096, 49.913209],
                    [-97.209091, 49.905691]
                ]]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Error:**

```
Error: error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Loop is not valid: [
            [ -97.209091, 49.905691 ]
            [ -97.206345, 49.918072 ],
            [ -97.17887899999999, 49.919399 ],
            [ -97.16514599999999, 49.907903 ],
            [ -97.16445899999999, 49.892865 ],
            [ -97.180939, 49.889326 ],
            [ -97.197418, 49.895077 ],
            [ -97.200165, 49.902596 ],
            [ -97.203598, 49.919399 ],
            [ -97.216644, 49.928682 ],
            [ -97.24479700000001, 49.927356 ],
            [ -97.25509599999999, 49.913209 ],
            [ -97.209091, 49.905691 ]
        ]
        Edges 1 and 7 cross.
        Edge locations in degrees: [-97.2063450, 49.9180720]-[-97.1788790, 49.9193990]
        and [-97.2001650, 49.9025960]-[-97.2035980, 49.9193990]
    ",
    "code" : 2
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've added an image of a brute force approach.

[Polygon Slicing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhja6.jpg)

- Basically it's doing a look ahead on intersects.
- If it finds one, it swaps out the points so that it stays within a loop.
- It would add the cut off as a "starting point" in some queue.
- When a look ahead goes around and finds it's own starting point we have a loop.
- Then keep going through the "starting point" queue until it's empty.
- The new set of polygons should contain all separate loops (in theory).

There are some issues with this though, it can get quite expensive going through all these loops. Say a max of 50 points would be about 1275 operations.

Also dealing with wrap around on 0/180 degreee coordinates could be a challenge.

Anyway, I didn't want to spend a whole day on this, I could even deal with a solution that does NOT deal with the wrap around condition.

Hoping there is a nice algorithm for this somewhere already I can just pop in (probably has some fancy technical term).

Also would be great if there was a more efficient approach then the brute force look-ahead.

Comment: some code sample would help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You said that you understand why is happening. (is it because is not valid polygon?)  Could you pls add to the question this info.

Comment: @PawelDubiel Yes, it's an invalid polygon because it's in the shape of a figure eight. So there are two lines that intersect. The question is how to deal with this.

Comment: I don't know if mongodb is really a good tool for what you trying to archive. I would consider postgis as it has such useful functions like http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html

Comment: What would you like to with the edge that is share by different holes? [see closed jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13735?focusedCommentId=651097&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-651097)

Answer (score 4):

It is because your coordinates are identical that creates an anomaly in the polygon shape: [-97.1788790,  **49.9193990**] and [-97.2035980, **49.9193990**]. In your code remove or change any of the duplicate coordinate,

```
"coordinates": [[
    [-97.209091, 49.905691],
    [-97.206345, 49.918072],
    [-97.178879, 49.919399], // this line
    [-97.165146, 49.907903],
    [-97.164459, 49.892865],
    [-97.180939, 49.889326],
    [-97.197418, 49.895077],
    [-97.200165, 49.902596],
    [-97.203598, 49.919399], // and this one
    [-97.216644, 49.928682],
    [-97.244797, 49.927356],
    [-97.255096, 49.913209],
    [-97.209091, 49.905691]
]]
```

Comment: Well, for the sake of trying, I modified the coordinate and it's still the error. But the issue is not duplicate coordinates, it's that two lines are intersecting (like figure 8 loop) which mongo doesn't seem to support.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in comments the better tool to query spatial data would be to use PostGIS.

For example PostGIS have the ST_validReason() to find the problem with polygon and a st_makevalid to fix but if this is not an option then I would create a service available to your PHP script with `shapely` python library https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely

http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

> The first premise of Shapely is that Python programmers should be able
>   to perform PostGIS type geometry operations outside of an RDBMS

Certainly `shapely` is a popular tool, and you should get future help with in on StackOverflow or gis.stackexchange.com from more experienced users

I think the problem you are trying to solve is not as trivial as it sounds.

So I would perform following steps:

1 Find how to do it with shapely

similar questions: 
  [Splitting self-intersecting polygon only returned one polygon in shapely in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110632/splitting-self-intersecting-polygon-only-returned-one-polygon-in-shapely-in-pyth)

2 create a simple php service which will pass query details to python script

3  Shapely will not prevent the creation of invalid polygon, but exceptions will be raised when they are operated on. So basically on such exception, I would call the script from step 1.

If this is just for one of query, I would just use QGIS software ( import points as CSV, create a new shapefile layer ( of type polygon ), and use Numerical vertex edit plugin )

**update**

I think the polygon should be fixed by the tool that created it so in this case, it should be a user. Maybe you fix that problem by looking from a different angle and if the shape is coming from the user and is drawn in GoogleMap in your app maybe enforce no intersection during drawing.

Found also this [Drawing a Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154899/drawing-a-polygon) ( sorting points and creating polygon with no intersection )

Comment: This seems a bit overkill. Although I'm not really sure what happens if there are multiple intersecting lines, I can imagine doing a brute force look ahead and just adding points along the path to remove the intersects. There is also the issue of the 180/0 degree wrapping. Trying to find some algorithm for it.

Comment: @Rob I think that area are very small, do you need really such complicated shapes. It's pretty easy to change this shape into a rectangle rotated area

Comment: The shapes are coming from a user drawn in Google Maps, so I can't really control if they make a few intersecting lines. It's not really a rectangle, it could be any shape really. So I wouldn't know what corners to act on.

Comment: @Rob updated answer ( not enough characters allowed in comment box )

Comment: That's not a bad work around. But I'm sure if the polygon changes shape suddenly the users will complain it's a bug (feature!) @pawel-dubiel

Comment: I've added some notes on what a brute force solution might look like but really hoping for some nice algorithm here.